# Python 3.x - writing generated letters as list to a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

(Code is cutted down bcs its most of the time the same)
Im having a Problem: I wrote a program that generates words / numbers based on user wishes and i want them to print in a txt file. 1 word per line.
The problem is, If i do this (look below) it works for all numbers/words that are only 2 letters. When I use 3 ore more letters, it looks like this:

(One per line, dont know how to do this in that post..)
A
A
AA
A
BA
A
CA
A
DA
A
EA
A
FA
A
GA
A
HA
A
IA
A
JA
A
KA
A
LA
A
MA
A
NA
A
OA
A
PA
A
QA
A
RA
A
SA
A
TA
A
UA
A
VA
A
WA
A
XA
A
YA
A
ZA
B
AA
B
BA
B
CA
B

the output in cmd is right, but txt file is wrong. So, did i something wrong? (ps. dont blame me for that shitty code, not the best ik)
(pps hope you unterstand the code bcs its writting in german :/)

```
from colorama import Fore
from colorama import init
from os import system
import itertools

AZ = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"


init()

def Menu1():
    print(Fore.GREEN + "Dies ist ein Listengenerator. Bitte wähle deine Einstellungen")
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Grossbuchstaben: ", Fore.RED + "1")
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Kleinbuchstaben: ", Fore.RED + "2")
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Gross- & Kleinbuchstaben: ", Fore.RED + "3")
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Zahlen: ", Fore.RED + "4")
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Grossbuchstaben & Zahlen: ", Fore.RED + "5")
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Kleinbuchstaben & Zahlen: ", Fore.RED + "6")
    print(Fore.CYAN + "Gross & Kleinbuchstaben sowie Zahlen: ", Fore.RED + "7")
    print(Fore.CYAN + "")
    user_input = input("")
    global x
    if user_input == "1":
        x=1

Menu1() 

if x==1:
    def x1():
        with open("Grossbuchstaben.txt", "w") as f:
            x = int(input("Minimale Zeichenlänge: "))
            y = int(input("Maximale Zeichenlänge: "))
            for n in range(x, y+1):
                for xs in itertools.product(AZ, repeat=n,):
                    f.write("\n".join(xs))
                    print("".join(xs)) #shows letters in console for seeing when its done
if x==1:
    x1()
```

Comment: This is a lot of code to expect people to look through. You should try debugging it to narrow the problem down.

Comment: Can you please cut down to the point in your code you suspect where the problem is? What troubleshooting have you done to help narrow down the problem? There is a lot of code here to go through. Maybe someone might come along and run this, but typically this isn't the best approach to get a fast answer.

Comment: Im sorry, but idk whats wrong.. It works perfectly with max 2 letters, but if I do 3, it bugs..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are saying that the output in the python interpreter is right but the output on the file is wrong, then maybe you should try actually writing the same thing.

In your code you output to the file

```
"\n".join(xs)
```

but you output to the interpreter

```
"".join(xs)
```

The first one will concatenate all elements of `xs` with newlines in between them, while the second one will just concatenate all elements of `xs` with nothing in between them.

You probably want to do

```
f.write("".join(xs) + "\n")
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer :)
if I use `f.write("".join(xs))` instead of `f.write("\n".join(xs))` the output in the file is not every word in a single line. Its all together in lines :/

Comment: @HealYouDown Great, make sure to accept this answer so that it stops appearing as unanswered. Also, your error was that print concatenates a newline on the string you are passing it while write does not.